# Passing input parameter with multiple values to other scripted calculation views in SAP HANA

Tags: database, hana

I have to pass input parameter (with multiple values) from a Graphical CV to scripted CV.
we can pass input parameter(single value) as:

```
PLACEHOLDER."$$inp_para$$" => :inp_para
```

but for input parameter(with multiple values) I tried using:

```
'PLACEHOLDER'=('$$input_para$$',:input_para)
```

and also

```
'PLACEHOLDER'=('$$input_para$$',*)
```

but It shows error, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass multiple parameters with this syntax:

```
(PLACEHOLDER."$$ZIP_PARAMETER$$" => :ZIP_PARAMETER)
```

Hope it helps